# Split string looking as array to array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have string `["10000", "10001"]` (please do not ask why it is string, I am fixing errors after one dude...) and now I have got problem with spliting each number as separate item, so for example I would like to have array like: `[10000, 10001]`, but I have big problem with writing proper RegExp. Now I am doing so:

```
items.gsub(/[^\d]/, '').scan(/./).each do |collection_id|
  my code here
end
```

which works with 1 digit ids, but not multi :-(. Could you help me please?

Comment: array of strings you have ?

Comment: Is this work - `2.1.0 :001 > string = '["10000", "10001"]'
 => "[\"10000\", \"10001\"]" 
2.1.0 :002 > require 'yaml'
 => true 
2.1.0 :003 > YAML.load(string).map(&:to_i)
 => [10000, 10001] 
2.1.0 :004 > `

Comment: It can be parsed as JSON, too: `JSON.parse(string).map(&:to_i)`

Comment: @Stefan Humm...Right, +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try using [`YAML`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) :

```
2.1.0 :001 > string = '["10000", "10001"]'
 => "[\"10000\", \"10001\"]" 
2.1.0 :002 > require 'yaml'
 => true 
2.1.0 :003 > YAML.load(string).map(&:to_i)
 => [10000, 10001]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string = '["10000", "10001"]'
string.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
# => [10000, 10001]
```

**Explanation**

`.scan(/d+/)` method returns an array of all the character blocks containing only digits:

```
string.scan(/\d+/)
# => ["10000", "10001"]
```

`.map(&:to_i)` executes the method `.to_i` on each element in the resulting array, and creates a new array from the results.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
"[\"10000\", \"10001\"]".gsub(/\[|\]|"/, '').split(",").map{ |s| s.to_i }
```

It:
1) replaces the characters [, ] and " with empty string.
2) splits resulting string on commas
3) map strings to integers and return the resulting array

Comment: would someone please edit and explain the answer?  This is part of our guidelines for a minimum-quality answer.

Comment: I think Uri already provided a decent resolution and the method names should be self explanatory. Thanks @Stefan for the edit though.